# Is it expected to have your contacts flooded with emails when synced to google account?

Tags: contacts, sync, gmail, google-account

I have only one google account which I use for email and syncing my phone contacts.

I do send a lot of mails.

I noticed that if I open my contacts every email address I've sent to appears as a contact on my phone. I feel flooded with contacts.

Is this expected? And how do I go about it?

I can unsync google but this will unsync gmail as well.

Comment: User [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.compelson.optimizer) and in edit contacts field [filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvEoF.png) to show contacts with email //Delete those contacts that are only email//AFAIK, they're isn't a way to prevent this from happening with Gmail unless don't sync (doesn't make sense because you need mails)

Comment: Thanks, I guess I just have to live with it. It's not like my Contacts is a holy book or something :)